# How to use jQuery to fadeOut() different parts of a single image ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The code :

```
$("#button1").click(function(){
    $("img").fadeOut();
});
```

fades out the whole element but I want to fade specific parts of an image like 4px from top and 2px from left .If CSS3 methods are needed , I am ready to do so.

Comment: I promise you guys , I will show you my new website once I get this algorithm of fading out an image -- Thanks to all **Stackoverflow** to help me

Comment: you can create an X number of masks, that are uppon an image (with `div`s, and create a function, that will hide tham in special or random order. It's not so difficult, but it needs time.

Comment: I understand it that clearly , could you please re-explain the masking of an image on more time. Anyways, thanks  @Andrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="image"></div>
    <div class="mask width100 height3 top0 left0"></div>
    <div class="mask width100 height3 top0 left3"></div>
    <div class="mask width3 height54 top10 left22"></div>
    <div class="mask width10 height30 top40 left12"></div>
    <!-- more masks goes here -->
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
}

.image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url(/*your url*/);
}

.mask {
    position: absolute;
    background: #000;
}

.width100 { width: 100% }
.width10 { width: 10% }
.width3 { width: 3% }
/* etc */

height3 { height: 3% }
height30 { height: 30% } 
height100 { height: 100% }
/* etc */

top0 { top: 0 }
top5 { top: 5% }
/* etc */
```

Your masks have `absolute` positions, and you can set their sides with `.widthXX` and `.heightXX` classes + position about the image with `.topXX` and `.leftXX` classes. (this is not ideal method, but it can be done fast)

Than with JS you can detect all that masks (with jQuery - `$('.mask')`) make an array of objects (if it's needed), and hide tham with `.hide()` or `.fadeOut()` methods in line order (0,1,2,3...) or randomly (get random index of array, hide it, and delete element from array).

Hope you understood my thoughts, and will make it better and more interesting :)

Comment: Hey bro @Andrew , you got a really cool idea .. Thanks bud !! [for helping me finish my website]

Comment: Hey bro , @Andrew you got a really cool idea - Thanks bud !! [for helping me finish my website] and Yeah --> I will certainly make it more interesting and share you the best webpage within a week .

Comment: Yeah Sure !! and you can expect your code in the page - source of my website .